Got same response from firestore while retriving data using startAfter
if (startAfterDoc) {
  q = query(collection(db, 'listings'), orderBy("id","desc"), startAfter(startAfterDoc), limit(4));
  console.log(q)
} else {
  q = query(collection(db, 'listings'), orderBy("id","desc"), limit(3));
}

For startAfterDoc I'm using whole doc as input.
Image when startafterdoc not defined:

Image when startafterdoc is defined:


What value are you specifying in startAfterDoc?

{id: 'E053E728-657C-411F-B585-A8859A326A85', neighbourhoodName: 'Washington Square Park', endsAtUnix: 1746345300, videoURL:......}
whole last doc of first response

Unfortunately not as I've never used Firebase. My previous comment was just a prompt for you to add some more useful detail to the question

I got solution ,just passing the startAfterDoc.id it's perfectly working , thank you for asking @RoryMcCrossan

@ParthM You need to pass a DocumentSnapshotto the startAfter()method. Can you show the code where you define startAfterDoc?

@RenaudTarnec I passed the whole document in startAfter, but then I realized I was ordering by id. When I passed the document id instead, it worked perfectly

@ParthM Instead of changing the title to "Solved" you should add an answer and then mark it as correct

Got the solution
I passed the whole document in startAfter, but then I realized I was ordering by id. When I passed the document id instead, it worked perfectly


 if (startAfterDoc) {
          q = query(collection(db, 'listings'), orderBy("id","desc"), startAfter(startAfterDoc.id), limit(4));
        } else {
          q = query(collection(db, 'listings'), orderBy("id","desc"), limit(3));
        }



